# Вывод двоичного числа в СИ

Tags: c

Пытаюсь вывести

```
 printf("%d",0010  );
```

но выводит 8. Как можно вывести 0010?

Comment: Самому, ручками

Comment: @avp без преобразования возможно вывести в этом чудесном языке? или нужно каждый символ обрабатывать и выводить?

Comment: 0010 не является двоичным числом в синтаксисе Си

Comment: `printf("%s", "0010");`, не?

Comment: @Qada: Для утилитарных целей место двоичного вывода в языке С занял шестнадцатеричный вывод. Если вам все это нужно "для дела", то пользуйтесь шестнадцатеричным. Если же вам нужен именно двоичный (ибо "задание такое"), то да - "каждый символ обрабатывать и выводить".

Answer (score 1):

Вы даете `printf` восьмеричное число 10 и просите напечатать его как десятичное. Вам выводится 8 - вы ждали чего-то другого?

Не существует спецификации формата для вывода двоичных чисел, поэтому их надо выводить вручную. В качестве примера:

```
// Вывод байта в двоичном виде

typedef unsigned char byte;

int main() {
  byte b = 93;  // Или любое другое
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    printf("%c", (b & 0x80) ? '1' : '0');
    b <<= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```